# Running a function when the game becomes active iOS - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

In my game in `swift` / `SpriteKit`, I have a problem when the user quits the app and opens it up again. If the game is on the pause menu and everything is paused, when the game is reloaded the game is unpaused but the labels on the pause menu do not disappear. How do I keep the game paused when I reopen it? I have tried

```
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1356))
    scene.view?.paused = true
}
```

But this is not doing anything. I have also tried `pause()` but that messes things up. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `applicationWillResignActive` function to pause your scene, by doing something like `scene.speed = 0` which will properly pause your scene (don't know why, but it doesn't quite work just using `pause`).  Here you can also display your pause menus (which you appear to be doing).

Then you want to use the `applicationDidBecomeActive` function to continue your game.  Here you do your checks to see if (guessing here) your "resume" button is pressed, and in the response method for that, set the `scene.speed = 1`.  Here your response method, do anything that requires starting back up (animations, actions, hiding your pause menu(s), or music).

I will say, these are the two functions that I use, you are free to use whichever two functions you would like that have a on/off kind of thing.  I've found these to be very reliable.

Comment: Xcode is saying that "value of type 'SKView' has no member 'speed'

Comment: My bad, see my edit.  You want to use `scene.speed`.

Comment: I put the speed to 0 in     func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
,     func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
,    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
, and     func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
but it is not changing anything...

Comment: You know, I think I read your question slight wrong, I thought you were trying to have the pause menu disappear when the user went back to the game.  Give me a moment to edit my answer again.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that the pause menu disappears. Or, have the game pause because what is happening is the pause menu fills the screen while the game continues. I tried scene.paused = true, scene.unpause() (gets rid of the pause menu), and the things you have suggested. None of the code I am writing in the AppDelegate is having any affect, what is causing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91143/discussion-between-gliderman-and-sam-acquaviva).